# Adding constraints to an IK hand bone in rigify?

Tags: scripting, rigify, bone.constraints

I want to rig a character with a staff with Rigify. The easiest way would be to have the IK hand bone in the generated rig parented to the staff bone, so that rotating the staff bone would also move the hand.

Unlike other rigify bone types (like basic.raw_copy), there doesn't appear to be any way to add constraints in the metarig and apply them to the IK hand control.

Adding the constraints in the generated rig means that they'd be lost if I needed to regenerate the rig. (This becomes absurdly time-consuming if I want to use more complicated constraints, like custom properties and a drivers to change the active constraints to let the character put down the staff, for example.)

I'm at a bit of a loss here. Is it possible to do this? I can't think of any way other than with a custom script in the Rigify "Advanced" panel, and I don't know enough about Python scripting in Blender to make that work.